# Boas práticas em C sobre chamada de "main()"?

Tags: c, funções

Estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo simples para trabalho de faculdade, e tenho dúvida em usar a função `main()` no código para em vez de sair voltar para o começo do programa, isso seria uma boa prática ou não?

Abaixo tenho um exemplo na minha função `cadastro()`, repare que no final do programa eu coloquei o `main()`, caso o usuário digitar 4, 5 ou outra tecla qualquer, fazendo assim que ele não saia do programa.

```
void cadastro(){
    int op;
    static int linha;

    cabecalhoCadastrar();

    do{
        //printf(":::::Cadastrar cliente:::::\n\n");

        if(linha >= 5){
            printf("\nAgenda lotada!\n");
            break;
        }
        else{
            printf("\nNome: ");
            fflush(stdin);
            fgets(cliente[linha].nome, 50, stdin);

            printf("Telefone: ");
            fflush(stdin);
            scanf("%d", &cliente[linha].telefone);

        /*  printf("Endereço: (rua, número, complemento): ");
            fflush(stdin);
            fgets(cliente[linha].endereco, 150, stdin);*/

            linha++;

            printf("\nCliente cadastrado com sucesso!\n\n\n");
            system("pause");
            system("cls");

            cabecalhoCadastrar();
            printf("\n1- Cadastrar cliente\n2- Sair\n");

            fflush(stdin);
            scanf("%d", &op);
            system("cls");
        }
    }while(op == 1);
    main();
}
```

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 2):

Como eu costumo dizer: esqueça boas práticas. Só pode seguí-las sem causar estrago quem não precisa delas, o que é um paradoxo.

É uma questão de estar certo ou não, e se é adequado ou não para o contexto.

Neste caso específico está errado. Pode até funcionar em exercício, mas se entrar várias vezes na função `main()` como está fazendo vai acumular na pilha e isto fará dar um estouro de memória em algum ponto.

Dependendo de outros fatores pode até causar outros problemas, isto é a pior coisa que pode fazer, um exemplo é quando usa o `static` que quase nunca é adequado, especialmente neste caso onde a chamadas recursivas sem querer.

Quando termina a execução de uma função deve apenas `return`ar para a função chamadora. Não deve nunca chamar a função chamadora ou outra que possa chamar a função chamadora para evitar um laço indesejado e estouro de pilha.

Tem vários outros erros nesta aplicação.

Comment: Obrigado Maniero pela seu comentário. Gostaria que aponta-se os outros erros conforme você verificou.

Comment: É muita coisa e já vira outra pergunta, o fato é que precisa repensar a forma que está aprendendo, procurar outra fonte.